# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue in device only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have table of images in my iOS app.when I am testing my iOS app in simulator, its working fine. but in device, when Scrolling the table it gives this error:Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.
 In my app there is no any warnings also. But still it is crashing in device.How to solve this error

Note: I am using ENSideMenu.when I am scrolling the table.this sidemenu delegate methods are calling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its possible that you may have silent complier about your warnings but it is possible that your app may over use memory i.e. memory is not optimised properly.

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.

Possibly there may be memory leaks or may be the memory overload (like view controller is remain in memory even after pop/dismiss due to strong reference to it.)

**How to check:**

- You need to build app with profile (cmd + i) and select `Allocation` from the options and then test you app.
- You will see the all the view controllers that is being allocates and deallocates during testing.
- Just identify the view controllers that are taking too much memory and try to optimise its memory.
- Also you can identify the view controller that remains in memory (not deallocates) even after pop/dismiss.